# Groovy: Escaping an arbitrary (unknown) regular expression

Tags: regex, groovy

I want to split a string via String.split(k) where k is an arbitrary string (read from intput). The problem is that k can be any string and thus may include regular expression operators, such as: `"*["`.

In such cases the split method fires an exception since the regular expression is not well formed.

What I am looking for is a way to escape any given k such that the resulting string can be safely passed on split().

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to escape regex patterns.